# Crear una columna calculada en base a una condición

Tags: sql, sql-server

Puedo crear una columna calculada en base a una condición? por ejemplo si la columna `id_condicion` tiene como valor "1" que me sume todas las columnas y si la columna `id_condicion` tiene como valor "2" tan solo que coja el primer valor de las columnas que están siendo calculadas.

```
ID_CONDICION  ENE FEB MAR ABR MAY JUN AGO SEP OCT NOV DIC AÑO_1
1             10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  120
2             10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor, gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Se puede, mediante una función que contemple esas condiciones. Te paso la url con la documentación de cómo hacer una funcion. No te asustes, es bastante sencillo de implementar una función.
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: y en donde se guardaría el valor calculado/copiado? Cual es el nombre de la columna donde lo quieres guardar?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear una columna calculada utilizando una sentencia `case` en la que evalúas el valor de la columna `id_condicion` y actúas en consecuencia. Por ejemplo, si es 1, sumas los campos de `ene` a `dic`, si es 2 solo *copias* el valor de `ene`.

El código habla más que mil palabras:

```
create table Prueba (
    id_condicion int
   , ene int
  , feb int
  , mar int
  , abr int
  , may int
  , jun int
  , jul int
  , ago int
  , sep int
  , oct int
  , nov int
  , dic int
  , anio1 as case 
               when id_condicion = 1 then ene + feb + mar + abr + may + jun + jul + ago + sep + oct + nov + dic
               when id_condicion = 2 then ene
             end
);
go
```

Le insertamos datos

```
insert into Prueba 
values (1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
     , (2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10);
go
```

Los consultamos:

```
select *
  from Prueba;
go
```

Y obtenemos este resultado:

```
id_condicion ene feb mar abr may jun jul ago sep oct nov dic anio1
------------ --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- -----
1            10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  120
2            10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10

(2 row(s) affected)
```